# Audio Queue buffer manipulation when paused

Tags: iphone, audio-streaming

I am wondering if there is a way to manipulate the audio buffer when the audio queue is paused. So the pseudo logic goes like this:
1. pause audio queue
2. manipulate the audio buffers in the queue except the one that is being handed to the callback function.
3. start the audio queue again

I notice the problem would be when I try to manipulate the audio buffer that is being decoded and fed to the device. So anyone has ever tried this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this path will lead to pain and suffering, and one that could be simulated without breaking the paradigm that AudioQueue sets forth.  The whole point of the queue is to feed buffers to a callback that you implement so you can manipulate each sample as you see fit before passing it down the chain.

Maybe if you can explain the context of what you're trying to accomplish, a more suitable solution could be offered.

Comment: Well what I want to do is to process the audio buffer sample data and I realize when I change the setting of this processing algorithm the affected samples are heard 2 seconds later coz of the queue... causing users to think that the application is lagging when applying the effect. Do you get me? I hope my explanation is not that confusing...

Comment: You should be able to reduce the size of your buffers and keep the latency very low... I would expect values in the hundreds of milliseconds range depending on what you're doing in the callback.  Although I don't think it's probably necessary, but the most drastic solution is to drop down another level in the abstraction stack and hit CoreAudio directly.  But again, you should be able to do much, much better than 2 seconds latency with AudioQueues.

Comment: I agree. Try a smaller buffer size and possibly more buffers.

Comment: Yeah this solution occured in my mind too...I am just worried about the buffer too small though... My signal processing takes around 0.3-0.4 second to fill a 1 second buffer so i am just worried of what will happen if i reduce the buffer size... but thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Well I tried your solution, and it works...mostly the problem comes when I try muktitasking as I listen to the audio queue playback... there are times when I can hear silences between audio playback which is probably caused by the smaller size of buffers. I guess I will put a multitask mode or something for this